# Can't load a win 8 boot from BIOS after Hard disk stuck (New is plugged)

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios

During my PC work (Surfing and playing some video) My PC stacked and restarted is self
I bought a new Hard disk (I thought my old hard disk died) connect it like the last one was connected) set from BIOS to load from my Win 8 CD
And all the time,the logo of the previous installed Win 8 appears and not the new installation that i am in need
Please help.
Btw i have an Asus p7p5d5 motherboard

Comment: Hmmmm.....I don't understand if you unplugged the OLD disk and plugged the new disk in its place.

Comment: I hard and old hardisk that i unplugged and plugged a new one..the win 8 CD is not loading it's installation

Comment: Logo for W8 install looks like W8 already installed, let the disc load, it takes time.

Comment: After 1-2 min error message appears for a split second and PC reboot it self..and all over again